# How to generate list of unique lines in text file using a Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, unique, lines

Suppose I have a file that contain a bunch of lines, some repeating:

```
line1
line1
line1
line2
line3
line3
line3
```

What linux command(s) should I use to generate a list of unique lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Does this change if the file is unsorted, i.e. repeating lines may not be in blocks?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you don't mind the output being sorted, use

```
sort -u
```

This sorts and removes duplicates

Answer (score 11):

`cat` to output the contents, piped to `sort` to sort them, piped to `uniq` to print out the unique values:

`cat test1.txt | sort | uniq`

you don't need to do the `sort` part if the file contents are already sorted.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new sort file with unique lines :

```
sort -u file >> unique_file
```

Create a new file with uniques lines (unsorted) :

```
cat file | uniq >> unique_file
```

Answer (score 1):

**If we do not care about the order**, then **the best solution** is actually:

```
sort -u file
```

If we also want **to ignore the case letter**, we can use it (as a result all letters will be converted to uppercase):

```
sort -fu file
```

**It would seem that even a better idea** would be to use the command:

```
uniq file
```

and if we also want **to ignore the case letter** (as a result the first row of duplicates is returned, without any change in case):

```
uniq -i file
```

**However, in this case, may be returned a completely different result, than in case when we use the** `sort` **command,** because `uniq` **command does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent**.